# Alter a column in sql table which is used a view

Tags: sql, alter-table, sql-view, alter-column

I would like to alter a column to increase the size of it from `[varchar](50)` to `[varchar](100)`.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestLegal]
    ALTER COLUMN [LName] [varchar](150) NOT NULL;
```

The above is query is failing because the `LNAME` column is being used in a view `vw_LegalCollection`.

Error:

> The object 'vw_LegalCollection' is dependent on column 'LName'. ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN LName failed because one or more objects access this column.

Is there anyway to modify the column in SQL table without that error? DO I need to drop the view and recreate it?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you do. So drop and recreate.

Good luck